What is the trade name for this kind of sheet metal cutter?
Is there a common trade name for a sheet metal shear that cuts by removing a strip, so as not to deform/bend the sides of the sheet like tin-snips do?
What are these things called:


That’s a nibbler of some description. I’m hoping a tin banger will chime in with specifics.

It's a Double Cut Metal Shear
https://www.tooled-up.com/blog/nibblers-vs-shears-which-is-best-when-it-comes-to-cutting-sheet-metal/

Double cut shears are so called because they use two separate cutters
which remove a thin strip of material as the tool is advanced through
the material. In this respect they leave a wider kerf, like nibblers,
but are much easier to clean up after. They also cut with minimum
distortion, as long as they are kept fairly straight; double cut
shears do not excel at curved cuts, and are not suitable for heavier
duty applications like single cut shears. However for many
applications in light gauge sheet metals, they provide a quick, easy
way of producing a clean cut that preserves the shape and structure of
the metal without creating excess waste.

